# Aspect of undefined in diferent file React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

[image: Aspec Error]

Iam trying to access camera but i get this error. I try to do all tutorial that people have show in other pages to make it work but i didn't have the same loki.

I enter at this file: **\myproject\node_modules\lottie-ios\Example-Swift\Pods\Target Support Files\lottie-ios\Info.plist** and add this:

```
 <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Feetit Would you like to access Camera</string>
 <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Feetit Would you like to access Photos</string>
```

Before that I install this:

**npm install react-native-camera --save**

**npm install react-native link react-native-camera**

After that I try this code for make Camera works:

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import Camera from 'react-native-camera';
 import {View, TouchableHighlight, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

 export default class CameraAcess extends Component {
     takePicture() {
    const options = {};
    //options.location = ...
    this.camera.capture({metadata: options})
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
}

onBarCodeRead(e) {
    console.log(
        "Barcode Found!", "Type: " + e.type + "\nData: " + e.data
    );
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Camera
                ref={(cam) => {
                    this.camera = cam;
                }}
                onBarCodeRead={this.onBarCodeRead.bind(this)}
                style={styles.preview}>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.capture} onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}>[CAPTURE]
                    <Text>Click me</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </Camera>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
},
preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center'
},
 capture: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 5,
    color: '#000',
    padding: 10,
    margin: 40
   }
});
```

I get this ERROR 'Can not read proprety 'Aspect' of undefined. The file of this error is other one, is Camera.js. Could Someone please tell me what i have to do to make it Work?

Comment: Where is Camera.js..

Comment: Have you checked with camera permission?

Comment: the Camera.js is in:

**myproject/node_modules/react-native-camera/src/Camera.js**

What permission do i have to add?

Answer (score 0):

I looked over the docs and did not see this variable on the camera required however i did see in an example I built that I set this variable on the Camera. See if this helps as it may not start with a default value.

```
aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}
```

Change to your preference.

Comment: Where I have to add this line? in my file project or in a especif file?

Comment: Inside Camera. Do it below onBarCodeRead

Comment: In file Camera.js I have many onBarCodeRead. which one my friend?

Comment: Inside the camera tags inside render. It is a variable for the camera

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this problem in iOS then

Remove the previously-installed react-native-camera pod.

```
 $ cd ios
 $ rm -rf Pods/
 $ pod install
```

And then manually link
as mentioned in librarary [readme](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera#manual-install)

Plese check the permissions also which are required for camera.

Comment: I have try this like this:

**npm uninstall pods**


**npm install pod**


I got the same issue :(